# How to simplify $x^{1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I study the roots laws and this is one of them:

$$\sqrt x = x^{1/2}$$

I don't know how simplify the $x^{1/2}$, what I mean is...

If for example:

$$x^{-3}=1 \cdot 1/x \cdot 1/x \cdot 1/x = 1/x^3$$

How do I simplify:

$$x^{1/2} = ?$$

**Edit:**

This edit is written to explain the meaning of **simplify**:

We all know that $3^3=1*3*3*3 = 27$

The **1*3*3*3** above is a simplification for $3^3$, in my question I ask if there is a way to **simplify** $x^{1/2}$

Comment: I'm not sure I'd consider $1/x^3$ to be simpler than $x^{-3}$.

Comment: Define "simplify".

Comment: $x^{0.5}$‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: You are just asking too much.

Comment: @barakmanos I edited.

Comment: You could call $27$ a simplification of $3^3$, but not $1\times3\times3\times3$. In fact $3^3$ is a smart (and simple) notation of  $1\times3\times3\times3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines are you trying to justify the result?

Consider:

$x^a \times x^a= x^1$

Using power laws you get $x^{2a}=x^1$

Comparing powers $a=\frac{1}{2}$

...but $\sqrt{x}\times \sqrt{x}=x$

so to preserve the power laws $x^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}$.

I think this is as simple as the identity gets but I like the expression by @logicmonkey for $x\neq0$

Comment: Loved the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy way to simplify $x^{\frac12}$, except by writing it as $x^{\frac12}=\sqrt x$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can you read my edit to so I can make sure you understood me and approve your answer?

Comment: @AvielFedida Yes, and still, there is no way you can possibly multiply $x$ by itself in such a way that you will get $\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

You might occasionally want to write it as $\frac {{x}}{{\sqrt x}}$

Comment: But $\sqrt x = x^{1/2}$ so how can you say that, can you explain...

Comment: This is not defined for $x=0$. I would call it a "complexification".

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: @drhab - I absolutely agree, obviously. But it's a relationship worth remembering in an engineering application where you might have a fixed inverse square root function block and a multiplier. Note my words "might occasionally".

Comment: @logicmonkey My downvote is locked now. If you make a small edit then I will be able to undo it.